# error creating App Mesh gateway route: BadRequestException: VirtualGatewayName must match ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, hashicorp, aws-app-mesh

I'm trying to implement AppMesh with ECS using terraform. Once I run `terraform apply`, during creation of `aws_appmesh_gateway_route`, I'm getting an error saying:

> Error: error creating App Mesh gateway route: BadRequestException: VirtualGatewayName must match ^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$.

Here is the code block which I'm using:

```hcl
resource "aws_appmesh_gateway_route" "test" {
  name                 = "test"
  mesh_name            = "test-appmesh"
  virtual_gateway_name = "aws_appmesh_virtual_gateway.test"

  spec {
    http_route {
      action {
        target {
          virtual_service {
            virtual_service_name = "aws_appmesh_virtual_service.servicea"
          }
        }
      }

      match {
        prefix = "/"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a string to the `virtual_gateway_name` argument which has a dot:

**aws_appmesh_virtual_gateway **.** test**

Just replace the dot with an underline: `aws_appmesh_virtual_gateway_test` or with something else which adheres to this pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`.